# Dynamic default selection for a drop down menu using url variables

Tags: php, get, drop-down-menu

I have several links on one page which all direct to the same page, but each of them passes a different variable in the URL (http://sitename.com/thispage.php?id=3).  I set new variables to true or false depending on which value is passed for "id", then put the true/false variables in to set the default option on an option tag like so:

```
    if (isset($_GET['id']))
        $id = ($_GET['id']);

    if ($id = 4)
        $id4 = true;
    else
        $id4 = false;

    ...

    <option value="Value" selected="<?php echo "$id4"; ?>">
        Value
     </option>
```

Excuse me if it seems messy.

I've got 12 of those setup, one for each menu option.  I can't seem to get it to display the correct one as the default selection though, as it always selects the 2nd to last menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you should correct is putting true and false in quotation marks, otherwise they will be converted from boolean to string and end up as a 1 or 0.

Or you could replace the whole thing with this

```
<option<?php if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == 4){ echo ' selected'; } ?>>
    value
</option>
```