# How to pass argument to html and process it by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not sure is it possible but I need something like this

1. pass argument to my html file (e.g a.html?status=failed)
2. somehow process this value by jquery to change select value

Comment: Like this: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.nl/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Comment: Try this way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808402/dynamic-default-selection-for-a-drop-down-menu-using-url-variables

Answer (score 0):

[Using URL Parser jQuery plugin](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var valuePassed=$.url().param('status');

 $('#select').val(valuePassed);

});
```

or with vannila javascript helper function explained in [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : 
                 decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var valuePassed=getParameterByName('status');

  $('#select').val(valuePassed);

});
```